# Decoding HTML tags in Laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel-5, ckeditor, decoding

I am using CKeditor for my Laravel 5.1 custom CMS. When I request content of stored pages in the database on my view, they appear with HTML tags like `<p>Hello world</p>`.
I have used `html_entity_decode()` with and without the charset specified to no avail.
It is also worth mentioning that I use Blade template engine at my view. Hence, my demo code looks like

```
$post->content = '<p>Hello world</p>'; // from the database from controller
{{html_entity_decode($post->content)}} //did not decode
```

I also tried using it in my controller instead and it did not change anything like this

```
$post->content = html_entity_decode($post->content); //before sending it to the view
```

I need your help to address this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing `{{html_entity_decode($post->content)}}`, 
try this:

```
{!! $post->content !!}
```

More info here https://laravel-news.com/2014/09/laravel-5-0-blade-changes/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in the controller

```
strip_tags($post->content);
```

or if you use in blade

```
{{ strip_tags( $post->content ) }}
```

see more info here [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)